# Finding (un)supported edges (igraph)

Tags: igraph

Let's say there is a following graph created in R igraph:

```
ed <- c(1,2,2,3,3,1,2,4,3,5,4,5,5,6,6,4)
gr <- make_undirected_graph(ed)
plot(gr)
```

I'm trying to separate edges of the graph into two groups: "supported", i.e. belonging to connected triangles (in the aforementioned example: 1-2, 2-3, 3-1, 4-5, 5-6, 6-4) and "unsupported", i.e. not belonging to connected triangles (2-4, 3-5). Is there any way to do that in igraph?

Comment: Can you please share your code to see what you have done and try to help you !

Comment: igraph has a `triangles()` function that returns all the triangles in the graph; you can use this to find the edges that are part of triangles.

Comment: @Tamás As I see, this function returns a vector of vertices ordered in paths of three each corresponding to separate triangle. Can you please suggest how to transform this vector into edge sequence containing edges which form the triangles? I have a big network, so I need to avoid loops, if possible.

Comment: @grendash Take the union of the edges with `union()`. Or call `c()` on them, and maybe `unique()`.

Comment: @GaborCsardi I'm sorry, but I don't understand. Can you please specify which edges are you talking about? When I implement `triangles(gr)` the output is a vector `2 3 1 4 5 6` of vertex ids. How can I get an edge sequence from it?

Comment: @GaborCsardi I found your reply [here](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2011-05/msg00106.html) relevant to current issue. Applying `cl <- cliques(gr, min=3, max=3)` and then `edges <- lapply(cl, function(x) E(gr, path=c(x,x[1])))` indeed does the job of finding edges which belong to triangles. However, `triangles()` seems to be more efficient than `cliques()`. So is there any way to apply the same approach with respect to the output of `triangles()`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found combining `triangles()` and @GaborCsardi's approach mentioned in my last comment:

```
tr <- triangles(gr)
edges <- tapply(tr, rep(1:(length(tr)/3), each = 3), function(x) E(gr,path=c(x,x[1])))
```

However, this solution is still rather inefficient in case of large network.